# exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH% (Golang)

Tags: go, gcc

Hola estoy intentando ejecutar una aplicación hecha en Golang al ejecutar mi aplicación con el comando go run main.go me arroja el error "exec: gcc: executable not found in %PATH%.
¿Alguna idea del por que me esta marcando este error?

Comment: puede ser que las variable de ejecución del S.O???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error se debe a que no se encuentra instalado el programa MinGW en tu ordenador para resolver este error debes instalarlo, actualmente la versión original ya no tiene sorporte, si estas usando windows de 64 bits debes instalar MinGW-w64, en mi caso instalando la de 32 y 64 bits no me funciono, tuve que instalar la de 64 bits especificcamente les dejo el enlace a la descarga.
[MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download)

1.- Debes instalar la versión de 64 bits o probar con ambas versiones no hay nada más que mover en la instalación más que el primer apartado de versiones.
Despues de la instalación te deberia de crear la carpeta "mingw-w64" en 64 bits

> C:\Program Files

Si instalaste en 32 bits.

> C:\Program Files (x86)

2.- Dirigite a la carpeta bin y copia la dirección de la carpeta por ejemplo en 64 bits

> ```
> C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin
> ```

En 32 bits:

> C:\Program
> Files(x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin.

3.- Crea la variable de entorno dirigite a las variables de entorno en variables del sistema edita la variable path y agrega una nueva variable solo copia la ruta del paso 2.
[image: Debe quedarte de la siguiente manera]

Eso seria todo funciona para windows 11.